# How to make such a Doughnut? Как сделать такой пончик?

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas

Tell me what kind of library in which you can implement this. At least so that you can add a border-radius to the arc. Maybe someone faced an approved task.

Подскажите какую нибудь библиотеку в которой можно реализовать подобное. Как минимум чтоб можно было добавить border-radius дуге. Может кто то сталкивался с подобной задачей.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это статическая фигнюшка или динамическая ?

Comment: Динамическая, нужно чтоб с анимациями была, и значения будут подгружаться разные

Comment: https://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/doughnut-chart-custom-inner-radius/ Посмотрите вот тут. Тут нет округлостей в окружности, но кажется можно вставить.

Comment: Я уже писал им в поддержку, говорят ничего подобного не получится сделать. А таких вариантов как у них масса. Но не могу найти ни один пока подходящий вариант. Сейчас смотрю на этот вариант https://www.amcharts.com/demos/dragging-pie-slices/#code

Comment: Там можно скруглить углы но нет градиента, или я пока еще не нашел. И не знаю пока как друг на друга наложить дуги. Вот тестовый вариант пока что https://codepen.io/mihazzz123/pen/mdJxqre

Comment: Я возможно сейчас не самое хорошее решение предложу, но может просто на месте стыков двух секторов размещать окружность того же цвет, что и один из пограничных секторов? За радиус взять просто ширину сектора.

Comment: Да но там градиент по идее должен быть, А при загрузке страницы они должны красиво выезжать - разворачиваться. Сейчас еще переговорим с клиентом. Возможно его устроит простой вариант

Comment: как бы эту штуку не сложно сделать но важно знать в каком виде будет приходить инфа- то есть от куда для pie chart возьмутся размеры ,,,из JSON или CSV....так на вскидку  нарисовал - посмотрите сколько там всего есть по этому важно знать откуда брать эти цифры: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/ZEGxrOB

Comment: Спасибо, Может что нибудь придумаю с вашим вариантом. Еще вопрос я могу задать им градиенты?  Значения скорее всего будут в json.

Comment: https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/PgYBEX